# Programação concorrente

Tags: c, thread, concorrência, lock

Olá, estou tendo dificuldades em encontrar o erro no código abaixo. É um problema em que idealmente, tendo 5 vagas disponíveis, qualquer um dos tipos de threads(servidor ou estagiário) podem ser sentar livremente, porém quando lotam as vagas, as próximas vagas são de preferência dos servidores, os estagiários só pegam as vagas caso nenhum servidor esteja esperando. Com o código abaixo, muitas vezes as threads entram em loop e não ficam esperando no pthread_cond_wait. Como eu poderia resolver?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "pthread.h"

#define VAGAS 4
#define SERVIDORES 5
#define ESTAGIARIOS 2

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t vez = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t lotou = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;                   
int contador = 0;
int contador_servidores = 0;
int contador_estagiarios = 0;

void mostra_que_quer_entrar(){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  contador++;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void servidor_trabalha(int i){
  printf("Servidor %d: vou trabalhar em uma baia!\n", i);
  sleep(2); 
}

void servidor_vai_para_casa(int i){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  printf("Servidor %d: vou deixar a baia.\n", i);
  printf("servidor mandou sinal\n");
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&lotou);
  printf("servidor enviei sinal\n");
  contador--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  sleep(2);
}

void servidor_fica_esperando(int i){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  printf("Lotado\n");
  printf("Servidor %d: vou esperar >:|\n", i);
  contador_servidores++;
  contador--;
  while(contador== VAGAS){
    printf("servidor esperando sinal\n");
    pthread_cond_wait(&lotou, &mutex);
    printf("servidor recebeu sinal\n");
  }
  contador_servidores--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void estagiario_trabalha(int i){
  printf("Estagiario %d: vou trabalhar em uma baia!\n", i);
  sleep(2); 
}

void estagiario_vai_para_casa(int i){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  printf("Estagiario %d: vou deixar a baia.\n", i);
  printf("contador %d\n", contador);
  printf("estagiario  mandou sinal\n");
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&lotou);
  printf("estagiario mandou\n");
  contador--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  sleep(2);
}

void estagiario_fica_esperando(int i){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  printf("Lotado\n");
  printf("Estagiario %d: vou esperar :(\n", i);
  contador--;
  printf("contador %d\n", contador);
  while(contador == VAGAS){
    printf("estagiario esperando sinal\n");
    pthread_cond_wait(&lotou, &mutex);
    printf("estagiario recebeu sinal\n");
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void* servidor(void * a){
  int i = *((int *) a);  
  while(1){

  mostra_que_quer_entrar();

    if(contador<=VAGAS){

      servidor_trabalha(i);

      servidor_vai_para_casa(i);

      break;

    }else{

      servidor_fica_esperando(i);

    }

  }
}

void* estagiario(void * a){
  int i = *((int *) a);  
  while(1){

  mostra_que_quer_entrar();
  printf("contador_servidores %d\n", contador_servidores);
    if(contador<=VAGAS && contador_servidores == 0){
      estagiario_trabalha(i);

      estagiario_vai_para_casa(i);

      break;
    }else{ 

      estagiario_fica_esperando(i);

    }
  }
}


int main(){

   pthread_t s[SERVIDORES];
   pthread_t e[ESTAGIARIOS];
   int i;
   int *id;
   for (i = 0; i < SERVIDORES ; i++) {
         id = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
         *id = i;
         pthread_create(&s[i], NULL, servidor, (void *) (id));
   }

   for (i = 0; i < ESTAGIARIOS ; i++) {
         id = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
         *id = i;
         pthread_create(&e[i], NULL, estagiario, (void *) (id));
   }

   for (i = 0; i < SERVIDORES ; i++) {
    pthread_join(s[i],NULL);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < ESTAGIARIOS ; i++) {
    pthread_join(e[i],NULL);
   }

   return 0;

}
```